# Better way to do multiple instances of IF statements when appending HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, json, if-statement, google-apps-script

Okay, so I have a script in Google Apps Script driven Web App, where I have a set of data in a Google Spreadsheet like so:

[image]

And in my **code.gs** I define my spreadsheet and get all the values, then I iterate through all of them and create variables that I then return as a JSON, like so:

```
function getOrders(){
 var ordersName = [];
 var subRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn());
 var orders = subRange.getValues();

 for (var i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {
    ordersName.push( { 
       status: orders[i][0], 
       type: orders[i][1],
       answer: orders[i][2]
   } );
  }
  return JSON.stringify(ordersName);
}
```

Earlier in my **code.gs** I also have an HTMLservice, creating an HTML page from the file **page.html**.

I run my function from my **page.html** like so:

```
$(function() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildOrderList).getOrders();
});

function buildOrderList(ordersName) {
  var arr = JSON.parse(ordersName);
  var rows = $('#orders');
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    rows.append('<div class="status">' + arr[i].status + '</div><div class="type">' + arr[i].type + '</div><div class="answer">' + arr[i].status + '</div>)
```

Then that JSON is parsed into my function buildOrderList, and then I use append to display the daya in an HTML element with the ID "orders" all that works fine. What I can then do is style the various div's that I created in the append, based on their class. So everything in status could have color: blue, and everything in type could be red and so on.

But if I want for there to be a difference in NEW and COMPLETED, that are in the same column, the I would have to do conditional logic, like this:

```
 if(arr[i].status === "NEW"){
 rows.append('<div class="status-new">' + arr[i].status + '</div>....)} 

 if(arr[i].status === "COMPLETED"){
 rows.append('<div class="status-completed">' + arr[i].status + '</div>....)}
```

Where I then just append a div with a different class for each of the, status-new and status-completed.
Which also "works" fine, but soon seems quite cumbersome, if I also would like to make the same distinction between LARGE and SMALL and ANSWERED and UNANSWERD. I would then need 8 different versions of the IF statements?

So my question is is there a way to make some conditional logic that defines the individual divs with their respective classes, before they are being appended? so first we see what the status is, okay it's NEW, so I this will be the HTML, then we see the type it's Large so this HTML, and so on.. and when done with everything in that row you move on to the next one.

I have tried some stuff, but I can't quite wrap my head around how it work outside of an extremely long IF IF IF IF THEN this.

All help is very much appreciated :)

Comment: Why not just do `rows.append('<div class="status-' + arr[i].status.toLowerCase() + ">' + arr[i].status + '</div>...');`?

Comment: You could use a switch, but also, you should not be concatenating strings of HTML. You should be using [Document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and using the DOM api. What you're doing right now is extremely messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an object with all the possibilities:

```
var objStatusToClass = {
  'NEW':"status-new",
  "COMPLETED":"status-completed",
  'LARGE':'className',
  'SMALL':'className'
};

var thisStatus,
    classToUse,
    html = "";

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  thisStatus = arr[i].status;
  classToUse = objStatusToClass[thisStatus];//Lookup class to use

  html = html + '<div class="' + classToUse + '">' + arr[i].status + '</div>....)
};

return html;
```

The `html` is a string, and will get received in the client side function as a string.  You are using `.withSuccessHandler(buildOrderList)`, so the return will be received by the `buildOrderList` function.  You can append the entire HTML in one command.

```
function buildOrderList(ordersHTML) {

  document.getElementById('orders').innerHTML = ordersHTML;
```

If you want to append HTML to existing HTML without deleting the existing HTML *from that element*, you can use:

```
document.getElementById('orders').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', ordersHTML);

//'beforeend' - Just inside the element, after its last child
```

Comment: Very cool, thanks for you answer, how would I handle the returned html, would you still suggest using the append functionality, or how will I specify where this html goes?